# Erasing a specific instance of an object from a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, erase

I have a class Circle whose instances I keep track of with these:

```
Circle *f1;
vector<Circle> list;
vector<Circle>::iterator it;
```

I have managed to create multiple Circles and got them to move around. How can I erase a specific instance of Circle? For example, if a certain circle hits a wall, then it should be erased. I've looked around at other questions and I even tried the code they gave out and no luck. Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {

    it->x += 1;

    if (it->x == ofGetWindowWidth()) {
        list.erase(it);
    }
}
```

I have gotten other statements to work with the if statement such as reversing the direction of their movement. list.erase(it); was a line of code I got from here and I don't understand why it crashes my program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); /* nothing here */) {

    it->x += 1;

    if (it->x == ofGetWindowWidth()) {
        it = list.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

The problem with your original code is that erasing an element invalidates the iterator to that element - the very same iterator you are trying to increment next. This exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

[list.erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) invalidates iterators to the erased element. Therefore, after you erase the element pointed to by "it", "it" is invalidated and the ++it, which follows after the for loops body, can crash your program. 
Rewriting your code to something similiar to the following should prevent your crash:

```
for(it=list.begin();it!=list.end(); ) {
    //your code
    if(it->x==ofGetWindowWidth())
        it=list.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the above code using `erase()` is that it invalidates the content of `it` when the element is being erase. You can use, e.g., this instead:

```
for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ) {
    it->x += 1;

    if (it->x == ofGetWindowWidth()) {
        list.erase(it++);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

The branch using `erase()` moves the kept iterator `it` off its current location before `erase()`ing the element. Only the temporary object return from `it++` gets invalidated. Of course, for this loop to work, you can't unconditionally increment `it`, i.e., the non-`erase()`ing branch needs its own increment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use erase with `remove_if`. This also works for removal of multiple elements. In your case it's

```
list.erase(std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
        [](const Circle& c){return c.x == ofGetWindowWidth();},list.end()),
```

Example with integers:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> str1 = {1,3,5,7};
    str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin(), str1.end(),
                              [](int x){return x<4 && x>2;}), str1.end());
   for(auto i : str1) std::cout << i ;
}
```

prints 157